# Give scores to dataframe based on id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is indexed by date, I am trying to provide scores for each accountid based on category, if that category value exist on the index date, this dataframe will look like this.

```
     accountid category Smooth Hard Sharp Narrow
timestamp                                             
2018-03-29       101   Smooth    1  NaN   NaN    NaN
2018-03-29       102     Hard    NaN  1   NaN    NaN
2018-03-30       103   Narrow    NaN  NaN   NaN    1
2018-04-30       104    Sharp    NaN  NaN   1    NaN
2018-04-21       105   Narrow    NaN  NaN   NaN    1
```

what is the best way to loop through the dataframe per accountid and assign scores for each category unstacked.

here is the dataframe creation script.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
idx = pd.date_range('02-28-2018', '04-29-2018')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[ '101', '2018-03-29', 'Smooth','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'], [
         '102', '2018-03-29', 'Hard','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'
    ], [ '103', '2018-03-30', 'Narrow','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'], [
         '104', '2018-04-30', 'Sharp','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'
    ], [ '105', '2018-04-21', 'Narrow','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']],
    columns=[ 'accountid', 'timestamp', 'category','Smooth','Hard','Sharp','Narrow'])

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df=df.set_index(['timestamp'])
print(df)
```

Comment: T,  dataframe displayed in the post is my desired output, when I populate the dataframe all the unstacked category values are NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use str accessor with `get_dummies`:

```
df[['accountid','category']].assign(**df['category'].str.get_dummies())
```

Output:

```
           accountid category  Hard  Narrow  Sharp  Smooth
timestamp                                                 
2018-03-29       101   Smooth     0       0      0       1
2018-03-29       102     Hard     1       0      0       0
2018-03-30       103   Narrow     0       1      0       0
2018-04-30       104    Sharp     0       0      1       0
2018-04-21       105   Narrow     0       1      0       0
```

And replace 0 with nan,

```
df[['accountid','category']].assign(**df['category'].str.get_dummies())\
                            .replace(0,np.nan)
```

Output:

```
           accountid category  Hard  Narrow  Sharp  Smooth
timestamp                                                 
2018-03-29       101   Smooth   NaN     NaN    NaN     1.0
2018-03-29       102     Hard   1.0     NaN    NaN     NaN
2018-03-30       103   Narrow   NaN     1.0    NaN     NaN
2018-04-30       104    Sharp   NaN     NaN    1.0     NaN
2018-04-21       105   Narrow   NaN     1.0    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I wanted, no looping, would you be kind enough to explain  ** syntax is for.

Comment: ** is keyword unpacking of a dataframe.  Basically it is taking the columns or pd.Series of the dataframe and join it back to the original dataframe.